# FireBase Facebook Auth Provider Error

Tags: javascript, facebook, twitter, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm messing around with the "FriendlyChat" example from the Firebase web app docs and I'm trying to integrate a Facebook Auth Provider rather than the Google Auth Provider in their example. I've integrated Twitter with ease and no issues, by simply creating a

```
var provider = new firebase.auth.TwitterAuthProvider();
```

variable and then calling

```
this.auth.signInWithPopup(provider);//'this' refers to the FriendlyChat object, and this code lies in a prototype function (signIn()) of that object.
```

which successfully allows me to login with my Twitter account. This exact method works with Google login as well, no issues.

However, when I take the same approach with Facebook:

```
var provider = new firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider();
this.auth.signInWithPopup(provider);
```

I receive a 400 error, and my inspector suggests that the error lies in the firebase.js code, which far exceeds my understanding of Javascript.

I've generated and applied the appropriate API Keys, Secrets, and Redirect URI's for Twitter and Facebook (Google login didn't require credentials).

If anyone else has encountered this problem and has a solution, it would be greatly appreciated! I'm new to Firebase, so I'm assuming I'm missing a small step.